# Speed up matrix evaluation

Tags: performance-tuning

I would like to define a function `func` using a combination of built in functions and obtain a similar speed in evaluation as if I evaluated those built in functions by themselves. Currently I am seeing a slow down. An example:

```
K[x_] = ConstantArray[func[x], {100, 100}];
K2[x_] = ConstantArray[Sin[x], {100, 100}];
func[x_] = Sin[x];
AbsoluteTiming[K[1.]]
AbsoluteTiming[K2[1.]]
```

> {0.00953596, {...}}
>
> {0.00413393, {...}}

The matrix `K2` evaluates significantly faster if I replace `func` by `Sin`, even though `func` is defined to be an alias of `Sin`.

My questions:

- What internal process leads to this time difference?
- How can I define `func` such that the times are comparable?

Comment: With `K2[x_] = ConstantArray[Sin[x], {100, 100}];` you will evaluate `Sin` 10000 times for each call to `K2`. Use `SetDelayed` i.e. `K2[x_] := ConstantArray[Sin[x], {100, 100}];`

Comment: Yes okay. `K` and `K2` are somehow representative for a large matrix with many built in functions that need to be evaluated. I want to keep the `Set` here and understand where the speed up comes from

Comment: In `K` it takes 2 top-level calls to compute each entry. In `K2` there is only 1 top-level call, so you should expect the time difference. If you change the 3rd line to `func = Sin;` the pattern matcher is skipped in the second call which makes the difference smaller.

Comment: How many entries are there in the actual matrix, and how many of the entries are the same?

Comment: It makes the time difference indeed smaller but its still there. What is a top level call and why does it take 1 less when defining without the `x`?

The actual matrix has dimension 1000x1000 and has no equal entries and evaluates `func` at different points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a smaller example:

```
Clear[func];
k[x_] = ConstantArray[func[x], 3];
k2[x_] = ConstantArray[Sin[x], 3];
func[x_] = Sin[x];
```

First compare the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues):

```
Information[k]
Information[k2]
```

> Global`k
>
> k[x_]={func[x],func[x],func[x]}
>
> Global`k2
>
> k2[x_]={Sin[x],Sin[x],Sin[x]}

Now, let's trace what happens:

```
Trace[k[1.]]
```

> {k[1.],{func[1.],func[1.],func[1.]},{func[1.],Sin[1.],0.841471},{func[1.],Sin[1.],0.841471},{func[1.],Sin[1.],0.841471},{0.841471,0.841471,0.841471}}

```
Trace[k2[1.]]
```

> {k2[1.],{Sin[1.],Sin[1.],Sin[1.]},{Sin[1.],0.841471},{Sin[1.],0.841471},{Sin[1.],0.841471},{0.841471,0.841471,0.841471}}

For `k` there is an extra top-level evaluation going from `func[1.]` to `Sin[1.]`. This extra evaluation accounts for the timing difference you see.

Comment: Trace is a nice command thanks for pointing that out! Is there a solution to skip this additional step apart from replacing `func` directly by `Sin`?

Answer (score 1):

Put in some colons, then the difference in execution times is almost not measurable (and the execution times get significantly smaller).

```
f[x_] := ConstantArray[func[x], {10000, 1000}];
f2[x_] := ConstantArray[Sin[x], {10000, 1000}];
func[x_] := Sin[x];
RepeatedTiming[a = f[1.];]
RepeatedTiming[a2 = f2[1.];]
a == a2
```

> {0.024, Null}
>
> {0.025, Null}
>
> True

By the way: Have a look what `??K` and `??K2` return you after you ran your code. Compare that with `??f` and `??f2`! Moreover, it's crucial in your code where you put the definition of `func`. If you put that in front, then there is almost no difference left.